# Определить тип предиката

Tags: синтаксис

> *В Англии считалось неприличным вязать на людях.*

Не могли бы вы мне объяснить, какой здесь предикат? Я сказала бы "*считалось неприличным вязать*", но мне трудно определить его тип.

Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Англии считалось неприличным вязать на людях.

Вязать - подлежащее; считалось неприличным - составное именное сказуемое, где считалось - глагол-связка,неприличным-именная часть, прилагательное.

Предикат-считалось неприличным. Семантическое значение - свойство.